# NodeJS after second post get 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have code for my router

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


function sendSolve(test) {
    // Some code for calculations
}
/* POST listing. */
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    sendSolve(req.body.data);
    next();
}, function (req,res) {
    res.json({"message": "ok"});
});

module.exports = router;
```

client code:

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    var $textArea = $('#textArea');
    var newData={data: $textArea.val()};
    $.post('/', newData, function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        $textArea.val('');
    });
});
```

and then i first `$.post` everythng is ok, but on second post im getting error 
    `500 (Internal Server Error)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4n.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ main.js:26n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3`

Comment: you probably need to add your front end code to the question since thats where the issue is being thrown from. if you use curl or postman do you get errors on multiple posts?

Answer (score 0):

`500 (Internal Server Error)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send` Looks like a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue to me. Pretty common with POSTs. One way to deal with this is to enable CORS via middleware. Example below:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Make sure to place that above your POST route. Hope that helps.

Comment: unfortunately not, still getting error 500; mb this is because i send data to terminal, then write answer of terminal in file?

Comment: ok, i solve it, in my calcs i've created a new Object outside router.post, then i move it inside it works good.
ty for help

Comment: Nice! Glad you figured it out!